# Combining two SharePoint forms in to one SharePoint form

Tags: forms, sharepoint

I have **two forms** from **two different form library** in SharePoint 2013.I want to **combine** both in to **one form**.
Can we do this in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Without any information about the form unfortunately I can't give you specifics however what you need to do is to have the form submit to the first document library. You can then setup a workflow on this document library that will trigger when a new file is created to create the content in the second library.

To learn how to do this I recommend reading Microsoft's [introduction to workflows documentation](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Introduction-to-workflows-15d0d459-cce8-4d8b-b34f-9ab6cda1075b).

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Okay i will explain then. Suppose I have three different forms which are created by using infopath and these forms use as templates in form library.(not a document library).I can named them as A,B and C. First I want to fill form A.Then I want  to fill only form C. Then I want to combine A and C as one document. Hope you understand the question now. :)

Comment: The easiest is to merge A/B/C in one form and hide/show only what you need. If you really need data to be in different forms, you can have 3 forms A/B/C which are different and you can use workflow to fill a form that can contain A and B and C data. You show only what you need. I clearly would not recommend the last solution.

Comment: Hey Sylvain,thank you for your answer but sorry I didn't get your answer.Please explain more.